# Scroll table-content horizontally but keep the row-headers in place

Tags: css, scroll, html-table, row, horizontal-scrolling

I'd like to create a table with row-headers. This table will most likely have too many columns to fit the screen (especially on mobile devices). As is has even more rows I can't swap rows and columns.

I guess the perfect solution for this would be row-headers that stay in place while scrolling the other cells horizontally.

I have no idea how to accomplish this. Simply setting the row-headers (td:first-child) to position:fixed doesn't work because scrolling vertically brings the row-headers and their rows out of alignment.

I created a little jsFiddle to experiment with: http://jsfiddle.net/uRu7g/

```
<table><tbody>
    <tr><td>RowHeader a0</td><td>b0</td><td>c0</td><td>d0</td><td>e0</td><td>f0</td><td>g0</td><td>h0</td><td>i0</td><td>j0</td><td>k0</td><td>l0</td><td>m0</td><td>n0</td><td>o0</td><td>p0</td><td>q0</td><td>r0</td><td>s0</td><td>t0</td><td>u0</td><td>v0</td><td>w0</td><td>x0</td><td>y0</td><td>z0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>RowHeader a1</td><td>b1</td><td>c1</td><td>d1</td><td>e1</td><td>f1</td><td>g1</td><td>h1</td><td>i1</td><td>j1</td><td>k1</td><td>l1</td><td>m1</td><td>n1</td><td>o1</td><td>p1</td><td>q1</td><td>r1</td><td>s1</td><td>t1</td><td>u1</td><td>v1</td><td>w1</td><td>x1</td><td>y1</td><td>z1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>RowHeader a2</td><td>b2</td><td>c2</td><td>d2</td><td>e2</td><td>f2</td><td>g2</td><td>h2</td><td>i2</td><td>j2</td><td>k2</td><td>l2</td><td>m2</td><td>n2</td><td>o2</td><td>p2</td><td>q2</td><td>r2</td><td>s2</td><td>t2</td><td>u2</td><td>v2</td><td>w2</td><td>x2</td><td>y2</td><td>z2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>RowHeader a3</td><td>b3</td><td>c3</td><td>d3</td><td>e3</td><td>f3</td><td>g3</td><td>h3</td><td>i3</td><td>j3</td><td>k3</td><td>l3</td><td>m3</td><td>n3</td><td>o3</td><td>p3</td><td>q3</td><td>r3</td><td>s3</td><td>t3</td><td>u3</td><td>v3</td><td>w3</td><td>x3</td><td>y3</td><td>z3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>RowHeader a4</td><td>b4</td><td>c4</td><td>d4</td><td>e4</td><td>f4</td><td>g4</td><td>h4</td><td>i4</td><td>j4</td><td>k4</td><td>l4</td><td>m4</td><td>n4</td><td>o4</td><td>p4</td><td>q4</td><td>r4</td><td>s4</td><td>t4</td><td>u4</td><td>v4</td><td>w4</td><td>x4</td><td>y4</td><td>z4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>RowHeader a5</td><td>b5</td><td>c5</td><td>d5</td><td>e5</td><td>f5</td><td>g5</td><td>h5</td><td>i5</td><td>j5</td><td>k5</td><td>l5</td><td>m5</td><td>n5</td><td>o5</td><td>p5</td><td>q5</td><td>r5</td><td>s5</td><td>t5</td><td>u5</td><td>v5</td><td>w5</td><td>x5</td><td>y5</td><td>z5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>RowHeader a6</td><td>b6</td><td>c6</td><td>d6</td><td>e6</td><td>f6</td><td>g6</td><td>h6</td><td>i6</td><td>j6</td><td>k6</td><td>l6</td><td>m6</td><td>n6</td><td>o6</td><td>p6</td><td>q6</td><td>r6</td><td>s6</td><td>t6</td><td>u6</td><td>v6</td><td>w6</td><td>x6</td><td>y6</td><td>z6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>RowHeader a7</td><td>b7</td><td>c7</td><td>d7</td><td>e7</td><td>f7</td><td>g7</td><td>h7</td><td>i7</td><td>j7</td><td>k7</td><td>l7</td><td>m7</td><td>n7</td><td>o7</td><td>p7</td><td>q7</td><td>r7</td><td>s7</td><td>t7</td><td>u7</td><td>v7</td><td>w7</td><td>x7</td><td>y7</td><td>z7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>RowHeader a8</td><td>b8</td><td>c8</td><td>d8</td><td>e8</td><td>f8</td><td>g8</td><td>h8</td><td>i8</td><td>j8</td><td>k8</td><td>l8</td><td>m8</td><td>n8</td><td>o8</td><td>p8</td><td>q8</td><td>r8</td><td>s8</td><td>t8</td><td>u8</td><td>v8</td><td>w8</td><td>x8</td><td>y8</td><td>z8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>RowHeader a9</td><td>b9</td><td>c9</td><td>d9</td><td>e9</td><td>f9</td><td>g9</td><td>h9</td><td>i9</td><td>j9</td><td>k9</td><td>l9</td><td>m9</td><td>n9</td><td>o9</td><td>p9</td><td>q9</td><td>r9</td><td>s9</td><td>t9</td><td>u9</td><td>v9</td><td>w9</td><td>x9</td><td>y9</td><td>z9</td></tr>
</tbody></table>



body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
td {
    padding: 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td:first-child {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two tables

1- One which will hold the row header

2- The one that will contain your data and that will be scroll able.

```
<table id="table-header"></table>
<table id="table-items"></table>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fVtyD/2/)

Not: I didn't remove the row header in the second table.

Comment: I updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fVtyD/3/  I think this might work. But there's a risk that the two tables get out of vertical-alignment because theres no link between row-header and row-content.

Comment: Well, you are right. there is no actual link between them but as long as the style for the table is the same you shouldn't face any problem. because you have one header row per content row so it's 1 x 1 relation.

Comment: I think I'll go with that, event if it's not 100% clean. I'll report you when its implemented and tested.

Answer (score 1):

your solution is here..

**Table.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>AJAX LIBRARY</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="superTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<DIV class=fakeContainer>
<TABLE class=demoTable id=demoTable>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TH>ID</TH>
<TH>First Name</TH>
<TH>Last Name</TH>
<TH>Age</TH>
<TH>State</TH>
<TH>Email Address</TH>
<TH>Favorite Color</TH>
<TH>Favorite Season</TH></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Jim</TD>
<TD>Neggi</TD>
<TD>25</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Jim.Neggi@gmail.com</TD>
<TD>Blue</TD>
<TD>Winter</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ID0001</TD>
<TD>Akriti</TD>
<TD>Sharma</TD>
<TD>28</TD>
<TD>Delhi</TD>
<TD>Akriti.Sharma@rediffmail.com</TD>
<TD>Purple</TD>
<TD>Summer</TD></TR>
</TBODY></TABLE></DIV>
<SCRIPT src="superTables.js" 
type=text/javascript></SCRIPT>

 <SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
 //<![CDATA[

 (function() {
var mySt = new superTable("demoTable", {
    cssSkin : "sSky",
    fixedCols : 1,
    headerRows : 1,
    onStart : function () {
        this.start = new Date();
    },
    onFinish : function () {
        document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML += "Finished...<br>" +        ((new Date()) - this.start) + "ms.<br>";
    }
});
 })();

 //]]>
 </SCRIPT>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**superTables.css**

```
 .sBase {
OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 100%; POSITION: relative; HEIGHT: 100%
  }
 .sHeader {
Z-INDEX: 3; POSITION: absolute; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff
  }
 .sHeaderInner {
POSITION: relative
  }
  .sHeaderInner TABLE {
TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed! important; WIDTH: 1px! important; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse!       important; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; border-spacing: 0px 0px
  }
  .sFHeader {
Z-INDEX: 4; OVERFLOW: hidden; POSITION: absolute
  }
  .sFHeader TABLE {
TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed! important; WIDTH: 1px! important; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse!   important; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; border-spacing: 0px 0px
  }
  .sData {
Z-INDEX: 2; OVERFLOW: auto; POSITION: absolute; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff
  }
  .sData TABLE {
TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed! important; WIDTH: 1px! important; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse!  important; border-spacing: 0px 0px
  }
  .sFData {
Z-INDEX: 1; POSITION: absolute; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff
  }
  .sFDataInner {
POSITION: relative
  }

  .sFData TABLE {
TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed! important; WIDTH: 1px! important; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse!   important; border-spacing: 0px 0px
  }
  .sDefault {
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; FONT-SIZE: 0.8em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;   MARGIN: 0px; BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; PADDING-TOP: 0px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, sans serif; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none
  }
  .sDefault TH {
BORDER-RIGHT: #cccccc 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px; BORDER-TOP: #cccccc 1px solid;  PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; BORDER-LEFT: #cccccc 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 3px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #cccccc 1px solid; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap
  }
  .sDefault TD {
BORDER-RIGHT: #cccccc 0px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px; BORDER-TOP: #cccccc 0px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; BORDER-LEFT: #cccccc 0px solid; PADDING-TOP: 3px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #cccccc 0px solid; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap
  }
  .sDefault TH {
BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: #c5c5c5; BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: #c5c5c5; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: #c5c5c5; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5e5; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: #c5c5c5
   }
   .sDefault-Fixed {
BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: #c5c5c5; BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: #c5c5c5; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: #c5c5c5; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #eeeeee; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: #c5c5c5
   }
   .sSky {
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; FONT-SIZE: 0.8em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; PADDING-TOP: 0px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, sans serif; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none
    }
    .sSky TH {
BORDER-RIGHT: #89BCCC 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px; BORDER-TOP: #89BCCC 0px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; BORDER-LEFT: #89BCCC 0px solid; PADDING-TOP: 3px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #89BCCC 1px solid; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap
     }
    .sSky TD {
BORDER-RIGHT: #89BCCC 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px; BORDER-TOP: #89BCCC 0px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; BORDER-LEFT: #89BCCC 0px solid; PADDING-TOP: 3px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #89BCCC 1px solid; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap
    }
    .sSky TH {
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #B9D8E2
    }
   .sSky-Fixed {
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #C8E0E8
    }
   .sOrange {
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; FONT-SIZE: 0.8em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; PADDING-TOP: 0px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, sans serif; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none
    }
   .sOrange TH {
BORDER-RIGHT: #cebb9e 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px; BORDER-TOP: #cebb9e 1px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; BORDER-LEFT: #cebb9e 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 3px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #cebb9e 1px solid; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap
    }
   .sOrange TD {
BORDER-RIGHT: #cebb9e 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px; BORDER-TOP: #cebb9e 0px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; BORDER-LEFT: #cebb9e 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 3px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #cebb9e 1px solid; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap
    }
   .sOrange TH {
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ecd8c7
   }
   .sOrange-Fixed {
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f7ede4
    }
    .sDark {
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; FONT-SIZE: 0.8em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; COLOR: #ffffff; BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; PADDING-TOP: 0px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, sans serif; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none
     }
    .sDark TH {
BORDER-RIGHT: #555555 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px; BORDER-TOP: #555555 1px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; BORDER-LEFT: #555555 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 3px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #555555 1px solid; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap
     }
    .sDark TD {
BORDER-RIGHT: #555555 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px; BORDER-TOP: #555555 0px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; BORDER-LEFT: #555555 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 3px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #555555 1px solid; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap
     }
    .sDark TH {
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #000000
     }
    .sDark-Fixed {
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #222222
    }
   .sDark-Main {
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #333333
   }
  .fakeContainer {
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 20px; OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 638px; BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; PADDING-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none;  BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; HEIGHT: 220px; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none;
border:1px solid #8DBFCF;}
```

**superTables.js**

```
     superTable = function (tableId, options) {
            /////* Initialize */
                    options = options || {};
                    this.cssSkin = options.cssSkin || "";
                    this.headerRows = parseInt(options.headerRows || "1");
                    this.fixedCols = parseInt(options.fixedCols || "0");
                    this.colWidths = options.colWidths || [];
                    this.initFunc = options.onStart || null;
                    this.callbackFunc = options.onFinish || null;
                    this.initFunc && this.initFunc();

            /////* Create the framework dom */
                    this.sBase = document.createElement("DIV");
                    this.sFHeader = this.sBase.cloneNode(false);
                    this.sHeader = this.sBase.cloneNode(false);
                    this.sHeaderInner = this.sBase.cloneNode(false);
                    this.sFData = this.sBase.cloneNode(false);
                    this.sFDataInner = this.sBase.cloneNode(false);
                    this.sData = this.sBase.cloneNode(false);
                    this.sColGroup = document.createElement("COLGROUP");

                    this.sDataTable = document.getElementById(tableId);
                    this.sDataTable.style.margin = "0px"; /* Otherwise looks bad */
                    if (this.cssSkin !== "") {
                            this.sDataTable.className += " " + this.cssSkin;
                    }
                    if (this.sDataTable.getElementsByTagName("COLGROUP").length > 0) {
                            this.sDataTable.removeChild(this.sDataTable.getElementsByTagName("COLGROUP")[0]); /* Making our own */
                    }
                    this.sParent = this.sDataTable.parentNode;
                    this.sParentHeight = this.sParent.offsetHeight;
                    this.sParentWidth = this.sParent.offsetWidth;

            /////* Attach the required classNames */
                    this.sBase.className = "sBase";
                    this.sFHeader.className = "sFHeader";
                    this.sHeader.className = "sHeader";
                    this.sHeaderInner.className = "sHeaderInner";
                    this.sFData.className = "sFData";
                    this.sFDataInner.className = "sFDataInner";
                    this.sData.className = "sData";

            /////* Clone parts of the data table for the new header table */
                    var alpha, beta, touched, clean, cleanRow, i, j, k, m, n, p;
                    this.sHeaderTable = this.sDataTable.cloneNode(false);
                    if (this.sDataTable.tHead) {
                            alpha = this.sDataTable.tHead;
                            this.sHeaderTable.appendChild(alpha.cloneNode(false));
                            beta = this.sHeaderTable.tHead;
                    } else {
                            alpha = this.sDataTable.tBodies[0];
                            this.sHeaderTable.appendChild(alpha.cloneNode(false));
                            beta = this.sHeaderTable.tBodies[0];
                    }
                    alpha = alpha.rows;
                    for (i=0; i<this.headerRows; i++) {
                            beta.appendChild(alpha[i].cloneNode(true));
                    }
                    this.sHeaderInner.appendChild(this.sHeaderTable);

                    if (this.fixedCols > 0) {
                            this.sFHeaderTable = this.sHeaderTable.cloneNode(true);
                            this.sFHeader.appendChild(this.sFHeaderTable);
                            this.sFDataTable = this.sDataTable.cloneNode(true);
                            this.sFDataInner.appendChild(this.sFDataTable);
                    }

            /////* Set up the colGroup */
                    alpha = this.sDataTable.tBodies[0].rows;
                    for (i=0, j=alpha.length; i<j; i++) {
                            clean = true;
                            for (k=0, m=alpha[i].cells.length; k<m; k++) {
                                    if (alpha[i].cells[k].colSpan !== 1 || alpha[i].cells[k].rowSpan !== 1) {
                                            i += alpha[i].cells[k].rowSpan - 1;
                                            clean = false;
                                            break;
                                    }
                            }
                            if (clean === true) break; /* A row with no cells of colSpan > 1 || rowSpan > 1 has been found */
                    }
                    cleanRow = (clean === true) ? i : 0; /* Use this row index to calculate the column widths */
                    for (i=0, j=alpha[cleanRow].cells.length; i<j; i++) {
                            if (i === this.colWidths.length || this.colWidths[i] === -1) {
                                    this.colWidths[i] = alpha[cleanRow].cells[i].offsetWidth;
                            }
                    }
                    for (i=0, j=this.colWidths.length; i<j; i++) {
                            this.sColGroup.appendChild(document.createElement("COL"));
                            this.sColGroup.lastChild.setAttribute("width", this.colWidths[i]);
                    }
                    this.sDataTable.insertBefore(this.sColGroup.cloneNode(true), this.sDataTable.firstChild);
                    this.sHeaderTable.insertBefore(this.sColGroup.cloneNode(true), this.sHeaderTable.firstChild);
                    if (this.fixedCols > 0) {
                            this.sFDataTable.insertBefore(this.sColGroup.cloneNode(true), this.sFDataTable.firstChild);
                            this.sFHeaderTable.insertBefore(this.sColGroup.cloneNode(true), this.sFHeaderTable.firstChild);
                    }

            /////* Style the tables individually if applicable */
                    if (this.cssSkin !== "") {
                            this.sDataTable.className += " " + this.cssSkin + "-Main";
                            this.sHeaderTable.className += " " + this.cssSkin + "-Headers";
                            if (this.fixedCols > 0) {
                                    this.sFDataTable.className += " " + this.cssSkin + "-Fixed";
                                    this.sFHeaderTable.className += " " + this.cssSkin + "-FixedHeaders";
                            }
                    }

            /////* Throw everything into sBase */
                    if (this.fixedCols > 0) {
                            this.sBase.appendChild(this.sFHeader);
                    }
                    this.sHeader.appendChild(this.sHeaderInner);
                    this.sBase.appendChild(this.sHeader);
                    if (this.fixedCols > 0) {
                            this.sFData.appendChild(this.sFDataInner);
                            this.sBase.appendChild(this.sFData);
                    }
                    this.sBase.appendChild(this.sData);
                    this.sParent.insertBefore(this.sBase, this.sDataTable);
                    this.sData.appendChild(this.sDataTable);

            /////* Align the tables */
                    var sDataStyles, sDataTableStyles;
                    this.sHeaderHeight = this.sDataTable.tBodies[0].rows[(this.sDataTable.tHead) ? 0 : this.headerRows].offsetTop;
                    sDataTableStyles = "margin-top: " + (this.sHeaderHeight * -1) + "px;";
                    sDataStyles = "margin-top: " + this.sHeaderHeight + "px;";
                    sDataStyles += "height: " + (this.sParentHeight - this.sHeaderHeight) + "px;";
                    if (this.fixedCols > 0) {       
                            /* A collapsed table's cell's offsetLeft is calculated differently (w/ or w/out border included) across broswers - adjust: */
                            this.sFHeaderWidth = this.sDataTable.tBodies[0].rows[cleanRow].cells[this.fixedCols].offsetLeft;
                            if (window.getComputedStyle) {
                                    alpha = document.defaultView;
                                    beta = this.sDataTable.tBodies[0].rows[0].cells[0];
                                    if (navigator.taintEnabled) { /* If not Safari */
                                            this.sFHeaderWidth += Math.ceil(parseInt(alpha.getComputedStyle(beta, null).getPropertyValue("border-right-width")) / 2);
                                    } else {
                                            this.sFHeaderWidth += parseInt(alpha.getComputedStyle(beta, null).getPropertyValue("border-right-width"));
                                    }
                            } else if (/*@cc_on!@*/0) { /* Internet Explorer */
                                    alpha = this.sDataTable.tBodies[0].rows[0].cells[0];
                                    beta = [alpha.currentStyle["borderRightWidth"], alpha.currentStyle["borderLeftWidth"]];
                                    if(/px/i.test(beta[0]) && /px/i.test(beta[1])) {
                                            beta = [parseInt(beta[0]), parseInt(beta[1])].sort();
                                            this.sFHeaderWidth += Math.ceil(parseInt(beta[1]) / 2);
                                    }
                            }

                            /* Opera 9.5 issue - a sizeable data table may cause the document scrollbars to appear without this: */
                            if (window.opera) {
                                    this.sFData.style.height = this.sParentHeight + "px";
                            }

                            this.sFHeader.style.width = this.sFHeaderWidth + "px";
                            sDataTableStyles += "margin-left: " + (this.sFHeaderWidth * -1) + "px;";
                            sDataStyles += "margin-left: " + this.sFHeaderWidth + "px;";
                            sDataStyles += "width: " + (this.sParentWidth - this.sFHeaderWidth) + "px;";
                    } else {
                            sDataStyles += "width: " + this.sParentWidth + "px;";
                    }
                    this.sData.style.cssText = sDataStyles;
                    this.sDataTable.style.cssText = sDataTableStyles;

            /////* Set up table scrolling and IE's onunload event for garbage collection */
                    (function (st) {
                            if (st.fixedCols > 0) {
                                    st.sData.onscroll = function () {
                                            st.sHeaderInner.style.right = st.sData.scrollLeft + "px";
                                            st.sFDataInner.style.top = (st.sData.scrollTop * -1) + "px";
                                    };
                            } else {
                                    st.sData.onscroll = function () {
                                            st.sHeaderInner.style.right = st.sData.scrollLeft + "px";
                                    };
                            }
                            if (/*@cc_on!@*/0) { /* Internet Explorer */
                                    window.attachEvent("onunload", function () {
                                            st.sData.onscroll = null;
                                            st = null;
                                    });
                            }
                    })(this);

                    this.callbackFunc && this.callbackFunc();
            };
```

Comment: I put it together in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GYZWE/  I like the bevahiour. But isn't there a CSS-way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
hello  the css looks like
td {
    padding: 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index:1;
}
td:first-child {
    width: 100px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
    background-color: gray;
}
td:nth-child(2){
    width: 100px; // width of first child
}

and your tr will be "<tr><td>RowHeader a0</td>**<td></td>**<td>b0</td><td>c0</td>......"

If it satisfy you please inform me.
```

Comment: I'm afraid, but that doesn't work. As I mentioned in my post vertical scrolling will not work anymore by setting the row-headers to position:fixed.

Comment: Sorry it is my fault, I overlook that part. And I think it is not possible widthout js or that kind of stuff !!!

Comment: For simplicity you may split the whole table in two part. First one for row-headers and second one for the other rows and then apply the required js. Once I apply this process to make a excell sheet like behavior.

Comment: css can do it. Then you have to either split the table; or keeping your original table add another table like 
<table id="mytab"><tbody>
<tr><td>RowHeader a0</td></tr>
.....
<tr><td>RowHeader a9</td></tr>
</tbody></table>                                                        then both of the table put in another table/s or div/s and make your css overflow-x/y accordingly to make one stable and other one scrolling horizontally. The vertical scroll will be remain. Mind that in this case scrollbar will be appear for the div or the table as per your css setting.

Comment: That's what Mahmoud Ibrahim suggested. I think I'll go with that.